# Not able to see Tomcat 8.0 in Runtimes of Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am Not able to see Tomcat 8.0 in Runtimes of Eclipse Kepler.
When I try to add the runtime as I have requirement for TOmcat 8

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this blog..Just copy all plugins & Feature to Eclipse installation directory.

http://nixmash.com/post/adding-tomcat-8-in-eclipse-kepler